# Pycharm: Navigating to JS source specified in require('path/to/file')

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, pycharm, marionette

Is there a way in pycharm to directly navigate to a file specified as a part of the require?

For instance, I have the import of the model randomFile.js

```
 var RandomFile = require('./path/to/file/randomFile');
```

When I create a instance like this:

```
 var rf = new RandomFile({'val': 'xyz'});
```

I would like to navigate to the randomFile.js when I hover & click on RandomFile.

For Django application mark directory as -> Sources root helped but this does not work for js files. Thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1) Select RandomFile in this line

```
var RandomFile = require('./path/to/file/randomFile');
```

2) Click Shift twice